# MySQL error: Unknown column in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table called `bank` with three columns: `uid`, `nick`, `balance`.

I am trying to create a query that will return the balance based on the nick, and I am getting an error `Unknown column 'Alex' in 'where clause'` when I use this query:

```
SELECT b.balance FROM bank AS b WHERE b.nick=`Alex` LIMIT 1
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you use backticks around "Alex" or are those singlequotes?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

backticks (`) are used for identifiers, like table names, column names, etc. Single quotes(') are used for string literals.

You want to do:

```
SELECT b.balance FROM bank AS b WHERE b.nick='Alex' LIMIT 1
```

Or, to be more explicit:

```
SELECT `b`.`balance` FROM `bank` AS b WHERE `b`.`nick`='Alex' LIMIT 1
```

When there is no chance of ambiguity, and when table/column names do not have special characters or spaces, then you can leave the ` off.

Here is some documentation that is dry and hard to read: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

But here is a related question on dba.stackoverflow that is easier to read: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23129/benefits-of-using-backtick-in-mysql-queries

And here is a very good page that I recommend everyone read: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?408497-the-big-bad-thread-of-quot-MySQL-Best-Practices-and-Other-Useful-Information-quot

Answer (score 6):

You are using the wrong "`"

Use ' instead

```
SELECT b.balance FROM bank AS b WHERE b.nick='Alex' LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use single-quote (`'`), not tick marks for values of your fields

```
SELECT b.balance FROM bank AS b WHERE b.nick='Alex' LIMIT 1
```

Tick marks are used to denote field names.

Answer (score -4):

Another reason for such an error is, well, *there is no such column* in the given table. Check spelling, letter case, typographic mistakes and the actual presence of the given field in the table definition.