# mysql query mistake opencart filter price

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, opencart2.x

I am creating filter module for opencart 2.0
Here is my code:

**model/catalog/product.php 

function getProducts()**

```
................................... SOME CODES.............
            //Filter products based on slider price range

            if ((isset($this->request->get['lower']))&&(isset($this->request->get['higher'])))
            {
            $sql .=  " AND p.price >='". $this->request->get['lower'] ." ' AND p.price <='". $this->request->get['higher'] ."'" ;
            }

            //Filter products based on price slider

        if (!empty($data['filter_manufacturer_id'])) {
            $sql .= " AND p.manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_manufacturer_id'] . "'";
        }
```

This works great for products don't have special.
But i am trying to apply this code for special.
So I am changing my SQL query to this:

```
    if ((isset($this->request->get['lower']))&&(isset($this->request->get['higher'])))
    {
    $sql .=  " AND (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END) >='". $this->request->get['lower'] ." ' AND (CASE WHEN special IS NOT NULL THEN special WHEN discount IS NOT NULL THEN discount ELSE p.price END) <='". $this->request->get['higher'] ."'" ;
    }
```

But it don't works for products which have special.

I got this error: `Unknown column 'special' in 'where clause'`

Comment: try the function `error_log($sql)` right before `$this->db->query($sql)` and make sure that the tables that contain special prices and discounts are in the query (I may be able to help if you post the resultant `$sql` here)

Comment: Please see this both answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142583/mysql-error-unknown-column-in-where-clause and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153598/unknown-column-in-where-clause hope, helpfully you.

Answer (score 0):

Add following before WHERE statement in sql

```
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special p2s ON p.product_id = ps.product_id LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount p2d ON p.product_id = pt.product_id
```

then use 'special' as 'p2s.special' and 'discount' as 'p2d.discount' on sql